# Vue js – Template or render function not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-mix

#### Background

I have a relatively old project built using `laravel-mix` with some Vue components and I thought I would update all of its scripts.

After making a number of changes I kept getting this error:

```
Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@2.5.13
- vue-template-compiler@2.3.3
```

At this point, I tried to `npm update vue` and `npm update vue-template-compiler` but had similar issues. I then followed some advice to "nuke" node_modules and install everything again.

I came up against similar issues *again* and made some changes to my `package.json`, reinstalled everything and now my build scripts work great.

#### The issue

In browser none of the components are loading. In the console, for each component on the page I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <WorldMap>
       <Root>
```

I have checked the following...

- the `<world-map>` tag is on the page and the `WorldMap` component is being loaded
- the component has an `export default {` in its script section
- My template is wrapped in template tags
- I've never needed a `render` function so don't have one, but I have looked at this as a solution
- Its also worth pointing out that all my files worked before I ran this update, so its either a Vue version or an npm version issue.

Am I missing a crucial vue module? A lot of my searches say something about having the run-time version of vue installed, but to date my setup has never needed any changes there.

**I am an npm noob so feel free to patronise me / over explain**

This is my package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "browser-sync": "^2.23.5",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bodymovin": "^4.13.0",
    "jquery-match-height": "^0.7.2",
    "medium-editor": "^5.23.3",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "rangeslider.js": "^2.3.2",
    "rellax": "^1.5.0",
    "vue-loader": "^13.7.0",
    "vue-sortable": "^0.1.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having this too, there was a breaking change introduced in one of the updates.

If you are using require to load your components, you need to add a .default call to the end.

here is my boot.js

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app-root",
    store,
    router: router,
    render: h => h(require("./components/app/app.vue").default)
});
```

And here is my router.js

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: require('./components/home/home.vue').default, name : "home" },    
...
];
```

Comment: Oh wow, you hero. In my case `
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue').default);` seems to have done the trick. I've done the same on all of my components